# How to insert data from sqllite database to remote mysql database using appcelerator titanium and php

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, appcelerator-mobile

I have tried using the following code. But it is not working. I have a temporary sqllite table, I need to insert all data from temporary database to remote mysql server.

```
var url = "http://bmcagro.com/manoj/insertopinion.php";
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
           onload: function(e) {
           // this.responseText holds the raw text return of the message (used for JSON)
           // this.responseXML holds any returned XML (used for SOAP web services)
           // this.responseData holds any returned binary data
           Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);
           var json = this.responseText;  
           var response = JSON.parse(json); 

           if (response.logged == "true") {
             var newtoast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
                          duration: 1000,
                          message: "Inserted"
           });
           newtoast.show();
           } else {  
                   var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
                   duration: 2000,
                   message: "False"
           });
           toast.show();
    }
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
         var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
                   duration: 2000,
                   message: "Error in Connection!!"
       });
       toast.show();
    },
    timeout:5000 });

    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.send({names: names});   
 });
```

and the php code is

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("MysqlSample.db.8189976.hostedresource.com","MysqlSample","xszZ@123ddlj");  
    if (!$con) {
        echo "Failed to make connection.";
        exit;
    }
    $db = mysql_select_db("MysqlSample",$con);
    if (!$db) {
        echo "Failed to select db.";
        exit;
    }  
    $names = $_POST['names'];
    foreach ($names as $name) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO seekopinion(uid,gid,opiniondescription,date,postedto) VALUES (" + $name.gid + "," + $name.tempid + "," + $name.gid + ",NOW()," + $name.gid + ")");
    }
    if($query)   {  
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM MysqlSample.seekopinion";  
         $q= mysql_query($sql); 
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($q);       
         $response = array(  
            'logged' => true, 
            'seekopinion' => $row['seekopinion']        
         );
        echo json_encode($response);  
     } else {  
             $response = array(  
                'logged' => false,  
                'message' => 'User with same name exists!!'  
            );  
        echo json_encode($response);    
    }
?>
```

actually iam a beginer in php as well as titanium...anybody pls help me out.

Comment: So what is not working?  Have you tried to debug your code at all?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: iam not getting errors in titanium code but insertion is not working

Comment: So what MySQL error are you getting? Have you done any code debugging to verify the query is printing as you expect?  Have you run the query directly against that database to see if it inserts properly? You have posted two significant chunks of code, surely you can hone down the problem to a few problematic lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found a way out ....
I changed the entire row to a string using delimiter '-' in appcelerator and then passed the parameter to the php code...from where the code is split using explode and then inserted using for loop

the appcelerator code for posting a table from an sqllite database to mysql database..

```
postbutton.addEventListener('click', function(e) 
{
var names = [];
var datarow ="";
var db = Ti.Database.open('weather');
var rows = db.execute('SELECT tempid,gid,name,email FROM postedto');
while (rows.isValidRow())
{
datarow=datarow+"-"+rows.fieldByName('tempid')
rows.next();
}
db.close();
var params = {  
                 "uid": Ti.App.userid,       
                 "opiniondescription": question2.text, 
                 "database": datarow.toString()
                   };  

var url = "http://asdf.com/as/asd.php";
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
           onload: function(e) {
           // this.responseText holds the raw text return of the message (used for JSON)
           // this.responseXML holds any returned XML (used for SOAP web services)
           // this.responseData holds any returned binary data
           Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);
           var json = this.responseText;  
           var response = JSON.parse(json); 
if (response.logged ==true) 
{
var seekopinion11=require('seekopinion2');
var seekop11 = new seekopinion11();
var newWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
                //fullscreen : true,
                backgroundImage : 'images/background.jpg',
                });
                newWindow.add(seekop11);
                newWindow.open({
                //animated : true
});
}
else  
{  
   var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
               duration: 2000,
               message: response.message
   });
   toast.show();
}  
},
onerror: function(e) {
Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
            duration: 2000,
            message: "There was an error retrieving data.Please try again"
   });
   toast.show();
},
timeout:5000
});

 xhr.open("GET", url);
 xhr.send(params);
});
```

the php code for breaking the string using explode

```
  <?php  
$con = mysql_connect("MysqlSample.db.hostedresource.com","MysqlSample","xszZ@");  
if (!$con)  
{  
    echo "Failed to make connection.";  
    exit;  
}  
$db = mysql_select_db("MysqlSample",$con);  
if (!$db)  
{  
    echo "Failed to select db.";  
    exit;  
}  
$uid= $_GET['uid'];  
$opiniondescription= $_GET['opiniondescription']; 
$database= $_GET['database']; 
$insert = "INSERT INTO seekopinion(uid,opiniondescription,date) VALUES ('$uid','$opiniondescription',NOW())";  
$query= mysql_query($insert);  
$rows = explode("-", $database);
$arrlength=count($rows);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
{
$insert = "INSERT INTO seekopinionuser(sid,postedto) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(sid) FROM seekopinion),$rows[$x])";  
$query= mysql_query($insert);  
}
    if($query)  
    {  
     $sql = "SELECT s.sid,s.opiniondescription,s.uid,u.postedto FROM seekopinion  s left join seekopinionuser u on s.sid=u.sid WHERE uid=$uid AND s.sid=(SELECT MAX(sid) FROM seekopinion) ";  
     $q= mysql_query($sql); 
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($q);       
     $response = array(  
        'logged' => true, 
        'opiniondescription' => $row['opiniondescription'],
        'uid' => $row['uid'] ,
        'sid'=>$row['sid']

        );  
    echo json_encode($response);  

    }  
    else  
    {  
         $response = array(  
        'logged' => false,  
        'message' => 'Seek opinion insertion failed!!'  
    );  
    echo json_encode($response);    
    }  
?>
```